# Верно ли выделять оборот «с одной лишь разницей»?

Tags: пунктуация

Верно ли выделять и как это обосновать?

"Техника исполнения второго варианта идентична первой, с одной лишь разницей, что вы выполняете кумбхаку не пару секунд, а подольше".

Comment: Фраза построена неверно: Техника идентична первому варианту(?!) Техника сравнивается с вариантом.

Comment: Так терпимо, но не очень хорошо (не совсем ясно, что такое первая техника?). Лучше как-то так: Техника исполнения второго варината отличается (от описанной) лишь тем, что, в  отличие от первого варианта, вы выполняете...

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не столько в способе обособления данной фразы, сколько в корректности её построения - это недопустимый гибрид двух разных выражений:

> 1. с одной лишь разницей:
> 2. с **той** лишь разницей, **что**...

К первому выражению нельзя добавить "что": указательный оборот "тот/та (факт, разница и т. п.), что" существует в языке, а "один/одна... , что" - нет.
Слева оба выражения отделяются запятой (последующее можно трактовать как уточняющую конструкцию). При этом в первом случае упоминание "одной" требует раскрытия (в чём заключается единственная "разница"), и после выражения предпочтительно двоеточие (допустимо и тире). Во втором случае перед "что" ставится запятая (присоединение придаточного предложения).

Answer (score 0):

Перед словами "с одной лишь разницей" обычно ставится запятая, а после них — двоеточие.

подобная ситуация вполне возможна и в наши дни, с одной лишь разницей: утруждать себя сочинением писем никто не будет ― поручат подчиненным и те «вправят мозги» по телефону. [Михаил Щукин. «Белый фартук, белый бант...» // «Сибирские огни», 2013] (Из Нацкорпуса)

Answer (score 0):

1) По технике исполнения второй вариант идентичен первому с одной лишь  разницей ― вы выполняете кумбхаку не пару секунд, а подольше.

Ставится тире или двоеточие.

Запятую можно не ставить, так как нет паузы.

2) По технике исполнения второй вариант идентичен первому, но с той разницей, что вы выполняете кумбхаку не пару секунд, а подольше.

Comment: "По технике исполнения..." — отличное решение проблемы!